# PHP if statement to execute a nav option if variable is true

Tags: php, html, html-lists, nav

I have a nav in html which has PHP code embeded into it, one of the "li" must show only if user is an admin user. I have already managed to configure the value for the system to recognize if the user is admin by checking the $is_admin variable.

This is the nav "li" that needs to be hidden if user is not admin (hence $is_admin != 1)

```html
<li class="nav-item <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'admin.php') { echo 'active'; } ?>">
<i id="icon" class="fas fa-cog"></i><a id="nav-text" class="nav-link text-uppercase " href="admin.php">Admin</a></li>
```

due to the fact it already contains PHP code I cannot do:

```html
<? php
if ($is_admin = 1) {
echo "
<li> that needs to be hidden if user is not admin (hence $is_admin != 1)
<li class="nav-item <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'admin.php') { echo 'active'; } ?>">
<i id="icon" class="fas fa-cog"></i><a id="nav-text" class="nav-link text-uppercase " href="admin.php">Admin</a></li>
"
}
?>
```

Any suggestions for a workaround please?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use sprintf to do this https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

```
<?php
if ($is_admin == 1) {

$adminNavItem='<li class="%s" > \n'
             .'<li id="icon" class="fas fa-cog"></i><a id="nav-text" class="nav-link text-uppercase " href="admin.php">Admin</a></li> \n'
             .'</li> \n';

$adminNavItemClass='';

if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'admin.php') { 
    $adminNavItemClass='active'; 
}

echo sprintf($adminNavItem, $adminNavItemClass);
}
?>
```

PS: Have a look at TWIG https://twig.symfony.com/ or https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php Writing PHP code directly inside HTML usually isn't such a good idea nowadays.

Although this was its original purpose as a templateing engine for CGI C binaries.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYTKm2oUzAg

Comment: figured it should be solved by adding this <?php if ($is_admin != 1) { echo ' hidden';} ?> and configuring hidden class in css to visible: hidden;

Comment: Well that is the simplest solution... I've done too much with templating engines to see it :>

Comment: Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: use display:none instead of visible:hidden then the Browser completely removes the element instead of just hiding it, but still allocating space.